# Как сохранить ссылку на себя в супер-конструкторе?

Tags: javascript

```
var Super = ( function( ){
    function Super( args ){
        this.init( args );
    }

    Super.prototype = {
        name: undefined,
        constructor: Super,
        init: function( args ){
            this.name = args.name;
        },
        toString: function( ){
            return this.name;
        }
    };

    return Super;
}( ) );

var Sub = ( function( SUPER ){
    function Sub( args ){
        SUPER.call( this, args );
    }

    Sub.prototype = Object.create( SUPER.prototype );
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

    Sub.prototype.init = function( args ){

    };

    return Sub;
}( Super ) );

var subOne = new Sub( {name: 'sub_1'} );
```

Возможно ли как-то сохранить ссылку на себя в объекте Super, для того чтобы не заниматься копипастом при переопределении методов в потомках?

**Добавлено:**

Или это самое время для приватных областей? Если делать так, то это не будет считаться нехорошо?

```
var Super = ( function( ){
    var _context,
    _init = function( args ){
        _context.name = args.name;
    };

    function Super( args ){
        // this.init( args );
        _context = this;
        _init( args );
    }

    Super.prototype = {
        name: undefined,
        constructor: Super,
        super: Object,
        toString: function( ){
            return this.name;
        }
    };

    return Super;
}( ) );

var Sub = ( function( SUPER ){
    var _context,
    _init = function( args ){
        // ...
    };

    function Sub( args ){
        SUPER.call( this, args );
        _context = this;
        _init( args );
    }

    Sub.prototype = Object.create( SUPER.prototype );
    Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;
    Sub.prototype.super = SUPER;

    return Sub;
}( Super ) );

var subOne = new Sub( {name: 'sub_1'} );
var subTwo = new Sub( {name: 'sub_2'} );

console.log( subOne.toString( ), subTwo.toString( ) ); // sub_1 sub_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация `super/parent` - это философский камень в мире JS, эликсир вечного холивара, [количество реализаций](http://rubaxa.github.io/friday/2014-02-07.html?full#14) просто зашкаливает, а ответа тут только два:

**ES5 Native**

```
/** @class Hello */
var Hello = function () {
    this.text = ["Hello"]
};

Hello.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.text.join(' ');
};

/** @class HelloJS @extends Hello */
var HelloJS = function () {
    // Вызываем родительский конструктор
    Hello.call(this);
    this.text.push('JS');
};

// Наследуем Hello
HelloJS.prototype = Object.create(Hello.prototype);

// Переопределяем метод
HelloJS.prototype.toString = function () {
    // Вызываем родительский метод
    var text = Hello.prototype.toString.call(this);
    return text + '!';
};

// Используем
var hello  = new Hello;
var helloJS  = new HelloJS;
console.log(hello + '', [hello instanceof Hello]); // "Hello", [true]
console.log(helloJS + '', [helloJS instanceof Hello, helloJS instanceof HelloJS]); // "Hello JS!", [true, true]
```

---

**ES6**

```
class Hello {
    constructor() {
        this.text = ["Hello"];
    },

    toString() {
        return this.text.join(' ');
    }
};

class HelloJS extends Hello {
    constructor() {
        this.super();
        this.text.push('JS');
    },

    toString() {
        var text = this.super()
        return text + '!';
    }
};
```

P.S. Либо TS, CS и другие *Script.

Comment: @vas проще перейти к практике, быстрей врубитесь.

Comment: Прочитал я Сошникова, из книг вычитал главы, ещё на habr'e статей много, и теперь уже эта запись не кажется такой уж дикой. Других же вариантов, покрасивей нет? )

И я вот ещё чего не понимаю... Почему не используют зону модуля для связи с контекстом?  
Ведь этобы в сто раз быстрее, чем call, работало бы, да и антипатерного в этом ничего нет.  
Получилось бы, что return - это публичный интерфейс, класс - это бы была реализация, а область замыкания была бы медиатором.